# how i make for use sha512 in my login form?

Tags: security, encryption, symfony

I have put in `security.yml`

```
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512
```

but i have also change this? :

```
$this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
```

with

```
$this->salt = base_convert(sha512(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
```

?

---

if I have this `security.yml`:

```
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512
```

and if i have this in `user.php`

```
$this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
```

when i make login return to me

> The presented password is invalid.

why?

Comment: throwing sha512 at the salt makes no sense at all. Bloating the salt doesn't increase its entropy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important property of a salt is being unique(or at least duplicates being rare). One way to do this is generating it randomly. You obviously need enough entropy. 128 bits is plenty, so there is no reason to have a longer salt than that.

Hashing the salt with sha512 does not increase the security at all. It just bloats the salt.